# Some counterexamples

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to know examples of the following statements.

If $V=S\bigoplus T=S'\bigoplus T'$, then $S\approx S'$ does not imply $T\approx T'$.

If $S$ is a subspace of both of the vector spaces $V$ and $W$, then $V\approx W$ does not imply $\frac {V}{S}\approx \frac {W}{S}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $S$ be infinite dimensional and $T,T'$ finite dimensional vector spaces of different dimension.

Comment: For a direct sum to make sense, isn't the intersection of $S$ and $T$ should be $0$?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb K$, then $V \cong \Bbb K^n$ for some unique $n$, and if $S$ and $T$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\Bbb K$, then $\dim (S \oplus T) = \dim S + \dim T$. So, if $V$ is finite-dimensional, $V = S \oplus T = S' \oplus T'$ and $S \cong S'$, we conclude that $T \cong T'$. In particular, any counterexample must have $V$ infinite-dimensional and hence at least one of $S$ and $T$ infinite-dimensional.

A similar hint applies to the question about quotients.

Comment: For the second one, we know that either both $V$ and $W$ are infinite dimensional or both are finite dimensional since $V\approx W$. Then in either case, actually four cases since $S$ can be either finite dimensional or infinite dimensional, why $V/S \not\approx W/S$?

Comment: In fact, if $V$ and $W$ are both finite-dimensional, then, $V / S$ and $W / S$ both have dimension $\dim V - \dim S$, so $\dim V$ must be infinite.